# Why malloc is faster than static memory allocation in my test program?

Tags: c, linux, performance, memory-management, x86-64

I have a test program. I get this result when executing it in ubuntu trusty 64 bit.

> malloc time:9571
>
> static time:45587

Why malloc is faster than static memory allocation,or my test program is wrong?

The test program is like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define TIME 10000

int data[1024] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,5,4,3,2,3 };
int st[TIME][1024];
int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int time = 0;
    struct timeval tv1,tv2;

    /* test for malloc */
    memset(&tv1,0,sizeof(tv1));
    memset(&tv2,0,sizeof(tv2));
    gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<TIME;i++) {
        void * p = malloc(4096);
        memset(p,0,4096);
        memcpy(p,data,sizeof(data));
        free(p);
        p = NULL;
    }
    gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL);
    time = ((tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
        (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec));
    printf("malloc time:%d\n",time);

    /* test for static memory allocation */
    memset(&tv1,0,sizeof(tv1));
    memset(&tv2,0,sizeof(tv2));
    gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL);
    for(i=0;i<TIME;i++) {
        memset(st[i],0,4096);
        memcpy(st[i],data,sizeof(data));
    }
    gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL);
    time = ((tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
        (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec));
    printf("static time:%d\n",time);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try repeating your test with the free() call.

Comment: @AndréPuel I guess you mean "without"

Comment: The first thing to do would be to inspect assembly code and see what's happening. The compiler could optimize out both tests since they have no observable behaviour .

Comment: `st` is 40MB, `p` points to 4KB. If you really want to test `malloc` versus static memory, you either need to malloc 40MB, or you need to make `st` 4KB.

Comment: @M.M When without free() call,malloc time is 39129 and static time is 45362.May be because malloc repeated use of the same section of memory

Comment: @Devin According to CS basics this not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That benchmark is essentially meaningless because most of what it is measuring has little relationship with the use of the two memory regions.

When your program starts up (that is, when execution of `main` commences), the default-initialized data segment (that is, the 40 megabytes of `st[40000][1024]`) has not yet been mapped into physical memory. The virtual memory addresses have been flagged for lazy mapping into zero-initialized memory, but this will not happen until the program actually attempts to reference those addresses. Each such reference requires kernel intervention to adjust the virtual memory map (as well as zero-initializing the page of physical memory). After that intervention, that page of virtual memory is mapped, but not any other page in the same data segment. So as you pass over the `st` array, you will generate a large number of page faults, each of which takes a significant amount of time. The vast majority of the time you're measuring in the "static memory" test consists of these kernel traps.

On the other hand, the first call to `malloc` will cause the standard library to initialize the memory allocation system. While that initialization is not too complicated, it is not free either. So most of the time you measure in the "malloc'ed memory" test consists of that initialization.

In order to do a meaningful benchmark, you need to make sure that all lazy initialization has been completed before you start measuring. One way of doing that is to perform the benchmark several times in the same executable, and discard the first (or first few) repetitions.

As an illustration, I modified your benchmark trivially by adding the following loop around the entire contents of `main` (except the return statement):

```
for (int reps = 0; reps < 4; ++reps) {
  printf("Repetition %d\n", reps);
  /* Body of main goes here */
}
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
Repetition 0:
malloc time:9584
static time:26923
Repetition 1:
malloc time:2467
static time:4360
Repetition 2:
malloc time:2463
static time:4332
Repetition 3:
malloc time:2413
static time:4609
```

Note the difference between the times measured in the "warm-up" iteration (repetition 0) and the remaining ones.

That still leaves a difference between the dynamic and static memory tests. Here, it's worth noting that the two tests use memory in different ways. The malloc test (probably) reuses the same buffer on every iteration, since after you `free` a block of memory, the next `malloc` of that size will probably immediately return it. The static memory test, on the other hand, cycles through the entire 40MB allocation. A better comparison would be to either `malloc` a buffer of the same size as `st` and cycle through it using the same code as the static test, or make `st` a single vector of 1024 ints (like the malloc) and reuse it using the same code as the malloc test. In other words, to compare two possible approaches, minimize the differences between the two. (I'll leave that as an exercise.)

If you make those suggested changes, you will likely find that the difference reduces to noise. But it is possible that there will remain some consistent (but small) difference, which will reflect the variety of hard-to-control for differences between the two loops, including alignment of code and data, and the precise details of the CPU cache. These minor differences would fit into the category of "coincidence", as ably articulated in [@seb's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506304/1566221). (While I think that it is important to understand avoidable pitfalls in benchmarking, I would emphasize that @seb's advice in that question is unquestionably correct.)

Comment: Thanks,when I add the loop and do not free the pointer of malloc,I get this output:`Repetition 0 malloc time:39767 static time:47314 Repetition 1 malloc time:36651 static time:27431 Repetition 2 malloc time:35223 static time:26704 Repetition 3 malloc time:35417 static time:28719`

Comment: @devin: if you never free any allocation, you are still comparing apples with oranges. (And if you're not optimizing, the results are even less meaningful.) You need to think about what you are measuring... Actually, you don't need to think about that. Think about writing good code, as seb suggests. Once you've got that down, you can think about squeezing the cpu cycles.

Comment: When `malloc` gets new pages from the OS, they are usually "lazily" mapped and will page fault.  I suspect what's happening here is that `free` isn't returning the memory to the OS so it's still on a free list, and thus the next malloc gets the same array that's still hot in L1d cache and TLBs.  Oh, you do say that in the 2nd half of your answer.  But the first half of your answer seems to imply that after `malloc` returns, you won't get a soft page fault for touching the memory.  That's not generally true for large allocations.

Comment: Or maybe you're just saying that the bookkeeping work of malloc is fairly cheap after the first call.  And BTW, some of the initialization stuff is done by glibc init functions (that run from `_start` or dynamic linker hooks before `main`), not by the first malloc call.  The first malloc call will probably need to `brk` or `mmap` some new memory from the OS, though, if glibc init didn't leave any on the free list.  Anyway, it looks like you're contrasting static allocation = page faults vs. mmap = something else, which feels misleading.

Comment: @Peter: I don't believe I imply that you won't get a page fault after malloc, and I certainly don't say it explicitly. I imply that you won't get another soft page fault if malloc returns the same memory as the previous call, and I assumed that most readers would figure that out for themselves. I'm not contrasting static allocation vs. mmap, though. I'm commenting on the observed behaviour of two concrete programs. I said in the first sentence of the answer that the comparison is meaningless, but obviously the programs have different timings, so the question is legitimate.

Comment: I was probably just biased the first time I read it because I was looking for a duplicate for [Why is iterating though \`std::vector\` faster than iterating though \`std::array\`?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57125253) where there isn't repeated alloc/free/memset, just one big initialized std::vector vs. one big uninitialized BSS array.  For the context of *this* question, yes your way of presenting it makes good sense.  I was just hoping to find an answer that accurately describes lazy allocation of BSS and mmap being similar, and didn't find it here.  But it doesn't belong here so that's on me :P

Answer (score 1):

Coincidence is not causality. Your CPU code cache probably fits the first loop (testing `malloc`) nicely, and then the second loop needs to be fetched from the slower main memory into the faster code cache, which biases your second timing.

There might a similar cache for data, meaning the static object `st` would be cached in faster memory than the memory allocated by `malloc` (or vice versa) for the entirety of it's duration. Emphasis should probably be placed on *might*. There's no requirement that this be the case. It is purely by coincidence that, as you've noticed, one is faster than the other.

You should not perform analysis of bottlenecks by rolling your own profiler to test the speed of theoretical bottlenecks, such as determining what storage duration is faster, because this can only lead to conclusions favouring messy premature optimisations throughout a solution, as opposed to mostly clean code with perhaps a tiny bit of mess.

Instead, you should focus on solving actual problems using clean, maintainable code. Once you have a program that solves an actual problem, you should use your profiler to determine whether it's fast enough, and if not, what parts of you code to optimise, so you can hope to keep most of your code clean.

Comment: All fair points, but this case is not coincidence so I don't think this is an answer. As hinted in a comment, the free() call means that the same memory will be used repeatedly in the malloc case, while the other loop uses 40 MB of bss, which will be lazily mapped into VM; the time difference is probably mostly page faults mixed with a bit of improved cache usage.

Comment: +nci You are wrong. The coincidence is that memory with allocated storage duration appears "faster" than memory with automatic storage duration, and make no mistake it is a coincidence. The cause of the coincidence is implementation details such as cache locality, though there is no requirement that this cause the coincidence.

Comment: @Seb Thank you for your advice,I will try to focus on actual problems using clean,maintainable code，then analyze and optimise

Comment: @seb: Let me be clear that I agree 100% with your advice. Nonetheless, I note that writing good benchmarks is not trivial. There are a number of common mistakes; and this is one of them. The actual cause of most of the massive difference is a failure to fully load the executable image before starting the benchmark. That's an avoidable error, and it has consequences which, imho, are not "coincidence". See my previous comment about lazy mapping of bss segments into virtual memory. I would agree that cache locality could be considered "a coincidence" (or even noise) in this case.